# NullPointerException in Application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am making a music player application.

its giving NullPointerException in a class.This is the code of player.java

```
package com.example.mudit.take6;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
   import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ListView lv;
    String[] items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvplaylist);

    final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findsongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    items = new String[mySongs.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        //toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3", "").replace("", "");
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.song_layout, R.id.textView, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class).putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("SongList", mySongs));
                                  }
                              }
    );

}

public ArrayList<File> findsongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (File SingleFiles : files) {
        if (SingleFiles.isDirectory() && !SingleFiles.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findsongs(SingleFiles));
        } else {
            if (SingleFiles.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                al.add(SingleFiles);

            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}

public void toast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

errors:-

```
04-16 01:00:56.575 17684-17684/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-16 01:00:56.640 17684-17684/com.example.mudit.take6 W/System:         ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mudit.take6-  1/lib/arm
04-16 01:00:56.822 17684-17684/com.example.mudit.take6 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-16 01:00:56.825 17684-17684/com.example.mudit.take6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.mudit.take6, PID: 17684
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mudit.take6/com.example.mudit.take6.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                         at com.example.mudit.take6.MainActivity.findsongs(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                         at com.example.mudit.take6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

How can i run it successfully. please tell if i am doing it wrong way . if you can tell in right way .
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is with your array. A quick way to debug this, is to add some logging after:
  final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findsongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
and
  items = new String[mySongs.size()];
and check their size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include permission in your `Manifest` file as you are trying to access external storage.
Since you are only reading SD card, so you can include read permission only  -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And if anywhere you are trying to modify the SD card contents you should include -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown on **line no 59**, which is 
`for (File SingleFiles : files)`, here files array is null, which is causing the `NullPointerException`.

change your code to validate whether files array is null.

```
public ArrayList<File> findsongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    if(files != null){
    for (File SingleFiles : files) {
        if (SingleFiles.isDirectory() && !SingleFiles.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findsongs(SingleFiles));
        } else {
            if (SingleFiles.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
               al.add(SingleFiles);

         }
     }
   }
}
return al;
```

}

Comment: i added this and there is no error but now mesongs has nothing inside it.its empty. i do not know why?

Comment: is there something wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array list "mySongs" is null. Check it by adding something like this into your code:

```
if(mySongs != null && mySongs.length > 0) {
   ...
}
```